# The uses of word information before 1948

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, ambiguity

The concept of information is very useful today, however it is used in different ways: number of symbols in a sequence, less description of a sequence, [a sequence that is useful for an agent](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02420.pdf), and much more.

A professor who teaches me Information Theory (the mathematical theory) said that Claud Shannon was able to capture precisely the common sense notion of the concept of information. However, since Shannon's work was successful, there is a risk that our use of the word common sense information may have been influenced by Shannon's own definition. And, consequently, the fact that Shannon's definition of information is very similar to one of the ways we use the word information may be a consequence of the very success of Shannon's definition. So, to avoid this bias, I prefer to look for the use of the word information before Shannon's work.

> What are the uses of the word "information" before 1948?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=information&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinformation%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/information

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Almanac_with_Information_Please

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? There are like 15 senses of the word that predate Shannon entropy, ranging from something mathematically defined (which predates and includes Shannon’s work) to legal senses to religious senses. Some of the senses are obsolete.

Comment: Where did you see that there are more than 15 senses of the word information?

Comment: @RaphaelAugusto The subscription-only OED.com. It’s so long there’s no way to even get a good screenshot of it even with everything collapsed, at least not on the device I’m on rn. But I tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL7Xu.jpg. All but one of the senses predates 1948.